# Docker on Windows getting "Could not locate Gemfile"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm trying to learn Docker using Windows as the host OS to create a container using Rails image from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/).

I've created a Dockerfile with the content below and an empty Gemfile, however I'm still getting the error "Could not locate Gemfile".

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rails:4.2.6
```

The commands I used are the following (not understanding what they actually do though):

```
ju.oliveira@br-54 MINGW64 /d/Juliano/ddoc
$ docker build -t ddoc .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
Step 1 : FROM rails:4.2.6
 ---> 3fc52e59c752
Step 2 : MAINTAINER Juliano Nunes
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d3ab93260f0f
Successfully built d3ab93260f0f
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.


$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby:2.1 bundle install
Unable to find image 'ruby:2.1' locally
2.1: Pulling from library/ruby
fdd5d7827f33: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
0f35d0fe50cc: Already exists
627b6479c8f7: Already exists
67c44324f4e3: Already exists
1429c50af3b7: Already exists
f4f9e6a0d68b: Pull complete
eada5eb51f5d: Pull complete
19aeb2fc6eae: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:efc655def76e69e7443aa0629846c2dd650a953298134a6f35ec32ecee444688
Status: Downloaded newer image for ruby:2.1
Could not locate Gemfile
```

So, my questions are:

- Why it can't find the Gemfile if it's in the same directory as the Dockerfile?
- What does the command `docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby:2.1 bundle install` do?
- How do I set a folder in my host file system to be synced to the container (I'm trying to create a development environment for Rails projects using Docker on Windows)?

I don't know if this makes any difference, but I'm running this command from the bash executed via "Docker Quickstart Terminal" shortcut. I think all it does is run these commands in a default VM, though I could create a new one (but I don't know if I should do this).

Thank you and sorry for all these questions, but right know Docker seems very confusing for me.

Comment: On Windows, you cannot mount files from a directory if the directory is **outside** your home folder (normally C:/Users/user_name).

Comment: @XiongbingJin Can you provide documentation or evidence of that? It sounds unlikely since a path is just a path and Windows doesn't have [chroot jails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chroot).

Comment: @Chloe Docker Toolbox for Windows uses the VirtualBox driver by default when creating the Docker `default` VM, and mounts the Windows User folder by default to that VM. You can use `--virtualbox-no-share` when creating the machine to disable this and use `--virtualbox-share-folder` to specify another folder. See https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/

Answer (score 1):

You must mount HOST directory somewhere inside your HOME directory (e.g. c:/Users/john/*)

Comment: Can you provide documentation for this claim? Can you explain why?

Comment: It's mentioned somewhere in docker docs...
Personally wasted some hours on this `feature`

Answer (score 0):

`$PWD` will give you a Unix-like path. If your shell is like Cygwin, it will look like `/cygdrive/c/Users/...` or something funny. However, Docker and VirtualBox is a Windows executable, so they expect a plain Windows path. However it seems Docker cannot accept a Windows path in the `-v` command line, so it is converted to `/c/Users/...`. The other people may be right; you may not be able to access a directory outside your home for some reason (but I wouldn't know why). To solve your problem, create a junction within your home that points to the path you want, then mount that path in your home.

```
>mklink /j \users\chloe\workspace\juliano \temp
Junction created for \users\chloe\workspace\juliano <<===>> \temp

>docker run -v /c/Users/Chloe/workspace/juliano:/app IMAGE-NAME ls
007.jpg
...
```

In your case that would be

```
mklink /j C:\Users\Juliano\project D:\Juliano\ddoc
docker run -v /c/Users/Juliano/project:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app ruby:2.1 bundle install
```

I don't know what `--rm` does. I assume `-w` sets the working directory. `-v` sets the volume mount and maps the host path to the container path. `ruby:2.1` uses the Docker standard Ruby 2.1 image. `bundle install` run Bundler!